# file.each_line can only be called once

Tags: ruby, iteration

I'm having some problems iterating through a file's lines, it seems like i can only use the each_line method once per file

```
file = open_file(path)
file.each_line { puts "Q"}
puts "--"
file.each_line { puts "Q"}
puts "--"
file.each_line { puts "Q"}
puts "--"
file.each_line { puts "Q"}

#Output: (on a file with three lines in it )
#Q
#Q
#Q
#--
#--
#--
```

it works fine with a regular iterator

```
3.times { puts "Q"}
puts "--"
3.times { puts "Q"}
puts "--"
3.times { puts "Q"}
puts "--"
3.times { puts "Q"}

#Output: (on a file with three lines in it )
#Q
#Q
#Q
#--
#Q
#Q
#Q
#--
#Q
#Q
#Q
#--
#Q
#Q
#Q
```

Is there anything i'm missing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to reset the file's read position using [file#seek](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-seek)

Try this

```
file.each_line &method(:puts)
file.seek 0
file.each_line &method(:puts)
```

---

According to a comment, the following will work too

```
file.each_line &method(:puts)
file.rewind
file.each_line &method(:puts)
```

---

Dummie content

```
# users.json
[
  {"name": "bob"},
  {"name": "alice"}
]
```

Ruby

```
# output.rb
file = File.open("users.json")
file.each_line &method(:puts)

#=> [
#=>   {"name": "bob"},
#=>   {"name": "alice"}
#=> ]

file.seek 0
#=> 0

file.each_line &method(:puts)
#=> [
#=>   {"name": "bob"},
#=>   {"name": "alice"}
#=> ]
```